# Next-auth - How to update the session client side?

Tags: javascript, next-auth

I manage to update my session serverside, with new user data, but event after assigning it to my session object in [...nextauth.js], my session client side remains the old one. It doesn't refresh, event if I use `getSession()`.

This code works for the back-end :

```
callbacks.session = async function session({ session, token }) {
  // we can fetch info from back end here to add it to the session   
  session.user = token.user;
  session.jti = token.jti;

  // If user is logged, we refresh his session
  if (token?.user?.id) {
    const url = routes.api.entities.shop.get.byId.build(token?.user?.id);
    let apiResp = await axios.get(url, {});
    session.user = { ...apiResp.data };
    token.user = { ...apiResp.data };
  }

  return session;
};
```

How can I refresh the session in front-end ?

Answer (score 38):

**UPDATE 2023:**
There is now an official way to do it as of v4.22.1. See [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/7056) and the updated [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#updating-the-session)

You now get an update function like this:

```
  const { update } = useSession();
```

**Note:** `update` fn [doesn't sync up the session object between tabs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#refetching-the-session), so if you have multiple tabs open, each tab needs to do `reloadSession()` separately.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

There is no easy **official** way to do it, it is still in discussion among contributors.

That said, there is a way. Next-auth does refresh session if you click on another tab, then on the one of your app. It happens, it is a javascript event we can reproduce.

So just define a method to do it :

```
const reloadSession = () => {
  const event = new Event("visibilitychange");
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Call it, and .. you're done. Session did refresh.

```
reloadSession();
```

For more information, this behaviour comes from [this part of the code](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/next-auth/src/react.tsx#L468)

Comment: Great 'hack' that works as expected.

Comment: For reference, [this](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/596#issuecomment-943453568) is where this hack was recommended on GitHub

Comment: Where I want to call this code @Yoann Buzznet

Comment: This doesn't work for V4

Comment: This works for me on next-auth version 4.10.3

Comment: Call the reloadSession() method any time you make changes and you want does changes to take effect. 

e.g.: updateUser(userId).then(()=> reloadSession())

Comment: Landed back to this answer to solve the same problem on another project. Happy to report that it still works.

Comment: any way to use this with SvelteKitAuth?

Answer (score 6):

Using the hack of simulating a tab switch does not works anymore in the v4.

What you could do is to update the callback to `session?update`.

```
const createOptions = (req) => ({
  // ...
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, ...params }) {
      if (req.url === "/api/auth/session?update") {
          const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/users/get/${token.email}`);
          const newUser = await response.json();
          token.hasAcceptedTerms = newUser.hasAcceptedTerms;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
        if (session.user != null && token.hasAcceptedTerms != null) {
            session.user.hasAcceptedTerms = token?.hasAcceptedTerms;
        }

        return Promise.resolve(session);
     },
  },
});

export default async (req, res) => {
  return NextAuth(req, res, createOptions(req));
};
```

Then in your client you can do a call

```
  await axios.get('/api/auth/session?update');
```

Tribute goes to [this answer](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/2269#issuecomment-933506368) on github.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case that anyone needs this. Here it is how to update the session when you make a change.

On your component you will do:

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
...

const {data: session, update: sessionUpdate} = useSession()
...

function handleUpdateSession() {
  sessionUpdate({
    info: //Your info here...
  })
}
```

And in your [...nextauth] you do something like:

```
callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, trigger, session }) {
      if(trigger === 'update') {
        if(session.info) {
          // update your token whatever you like
        }
      }
      
      return token;
    }
}
```

`trigger` are triggered in 3 scenarios (Signin, SignUp and Update) and `session` receives what you send on your update call. In this case it will be just an object like:

```
{
  info: some info here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [update()](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#updating-the-session)  method is now available.

> The useSession() hook exposes a `update(data?: any): Promise<Session | null>` method that can be used to update the session, without reloading the page.
> You can optionally pass an arbitrary object as the first argument, which will be accessible on the server to merge with the session object.
> If you are not passing any argument, the session will be reloaded from the server. (This is useful if you want to update the session after a server-side mutation, like updating in the database.)

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Page() {
  const { data: session, status, update } = useSession()

  if (status === "authenticated") {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Signed in as {session.user.name}</p>
        
        {/* Update the value by sending it to the backend. */}
        <button onClick={() => update({ name: "John Doe" })}>
          Edit name
        </button>
        {/*
          * Only trigger a session update, assuming you already updated the value server-side.
          * All `useSession().data` references will be updated.
          */}
        <button onClick={() => update()}>
          Edit name
        </button>
      </>
    )
  }

  return <a href="/api/auth/signin">Sign in</a>
}
```

Comment: any way to use this with SvelteKitAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone comes here to figure out how to get the session info into an analytics platform like Heap, I ended up creating a component that uses `useSession`.

```
export default function HeapAnalytics() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated" && window.heap) {
      console.info("Identifying Heap User...");
      window.heap.identify(session.user.email);
      window.heap.addUserProperties({
        name: session.user.name,
        userId: session.user.id,
      });
    }
  }, [scriptLoaded, session, status]);

  const scriptReady = () => {
    if (window.heap) {
      setScriptLoaded(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Script
      id="heap-analytics"
      strategy="afterInteractive"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
      window.heap=window.heap||[],heap.load=function(e,t){window.heap.appid=e,window.heap.config=t=t||{};var r=document.createElement("script");r.type="text/javascript",r.async=!0,r.src="https://cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-"+e+".js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(r,a);for(var n=function(e){return function(){heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},p=["addEventProperties","addUserProperties","clearEventProperties","identify","resetIdentity","removeEventProperty","setEventProperties","track","unsetEventProperty"],o=0;o<p.length;o++)heap[p[o]]=n(p[o])};
      heap.load("${config.tags.HEAP_ANALYTICS}");
      `,
      }}
      onReady={scriptReady}
    />
  );
}
```

Full documentation: https://samelogic.com/blog/heap-analytics-in-nextjs-with-nextauthjs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the session using `getSession()` then try this:

```
import { getSession, getCsrfToken } from 'next-auth/react'
... 
const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken()
const updatedSession = await getSession({ req: {
                  body: {
                    csrfToken,
                    data: { user: { accessToken: "newToken" } },
                  },
                },
              })
...
```

and in callbacks:

```
 async jwt({ token, session, trigger }) {
   if (trigger === 'update' && session?.user?.accessToken) {
   token.accessToken= session.user.accessToken
  }

  return token
},

async session({ session, token }) {
  session.user = token
  return session
},
```